# How to setup a word document page?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have created a table in Excel application using with VBA code and i copied the same table into the word document, here my question is i want to change the word document page setup, can any one correct my code.
thanks...

```
Sub word_page_setup()

    With Documents("Document1.doc").pagesetup
        .LeftMargin = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .RightMargin = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .TopMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
        .BottomMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: We cannot correct your code because you didn't tell what's wrong with it, nor did you tell what you expect it to do or if you get any errors. Please read [mcve].

Comment: it's showing the error is "Sub or function not defined"

Comment: could you please correct my code and re-post it....thanks for your immediate replay

Comment: No, I can't because It is unclear what the issue is. Try changing it to `Application.InchesToPoints`

Comment: Please tell us on which line the error is occurring and whether this code is running in Word or in Excel. If in Excel, show us other code that's running successfully in Excel to work with Word. Without this information no one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to set the margins in the document named Document1.doc, this would do it.

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub word_page_setup()
        Dim doc As Document
        Dim doctest As Document
        Dim doccol As Documents
        Set doccol = Documents
        ' find the document named Document1.doc
        For Each doctest In Documents
            If doctest.Name = "Document1.doc" Then Set doc = doctest
        Next
        ' if we didn't find it then exit
        If doc Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        ' set margins
        With doc.PageSetup
            .LeftMargin = InchesToPoints(0.5)
            .RightMargin = InchesToPoints(0.5)
            .TopMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
            .BottomMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
        End With
    End Sub
```